# Confusion for the purpose of DirectoryInfo.Delete(bool recursive)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, delete-directory

The method `DirectoryInfo.Delete(bool recursive)` takes a Boolean parameter which represents whether the delete should be recursive or not.

But why is there an option here, how could you delete a directory if it was not recursive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delete a non-empty directory when recursive flag is off.

From [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c66e2tts(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the DirectoryInfo has no files or subdirectories, this method deletes the DirectoryInfo even if recursive is false. Attempting to delete a DirectoryInfo that is not empty when recursive is false throws an IOException.